# Images not showing in sharepoint print out

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010, and created some custom visual web parts.  On these web parts's html, i am displaying images, found under the layouts folder.

They show up correctly, however, when I do print preview of the site or try to print the page, the images disappear!

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of CSS, SharePoint by default hides few elements when you print using a different CSS for Print, refer to this [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to see how it works. Check if your image is being hidden using above method.